# I am trying to access database name in model relationshipt by config using laravel 8

Tags: laravel

Hi i am trying to  access database name by using config but unfortunately it's not working please help me how can i resolve that thanks.

**Property model**

```
 public function editedBy()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User',config('database.connections.web.database'), 'property_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

**app/config/database/**

```
 'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

   
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_WEB_HOST'),
            'port' => env('DB_WEB_PORT'),
            'database' => env('DB_WEB_DATABASE'),
            'username' => env('DB_WEB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('DB_WEB_PASSWORD'),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

    ],
```

Comment: whats the error showing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using to database name using env('DB_DATABASE'). Its displaying that you have change the default variables so, it may be like this in your case.

```
  public function editedBy()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\User',env('DB_WEB_DATABASE'), 'property_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
        }
```

or if you really want to use config this is the example.

```
 public function getDatabaseName()
{
    $databaseName = Config::get('database.connections.'.Config::get('database.default'));

    dd($databaseName['database']);
}
```